# TeXing special japanese characters

Tags: fonts, symbols, cjk, japanese

I want to TeX the Japanese characters 因子の部屋 (lit. "factor rooms"). How do I do that with LaTeX?

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way with the `pdflatex` engine is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{document}

\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}因子の部屋\end{CJK}

\end{document}
```

If you want an abbreviated command for typesetting Japanese fragments, then put this in the preamble

```
\newcommand{\textnihon}{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}\nihon}
\newcommand{\nihon}[1]{#1\end{CJK}}
```

Now

```
\textnihon{因子の部屋}
```

will typeset the fragment.

Another way to cope with the problem is to switch to XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX; with one of these engines, the document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\nihon}{Hiragino Mincho Pro}
\newcommand{\textnihon}[1]{{\nihon#1}}

\begin{document}
This is a Japanese fragment: \textnihon{因子の部屋}
\end{document}
```

In place of "Hiragino Mincho Pro" you'll need to use a Japanese font present on your system.

Comment: `inputenc` package with `utf8` option is not useful. I'm not sure if it is harmful.

Comment: I thought if `inputenc` is used with `utf8` option, and the file is saved in UTF8 encoding, then the `CJKutf8` package should be loaded instead of `CJK`.