# Critical Package xeCJK Error: The xeCJK package requires XeTeX to function

Tags: pdftex, xecjk, rendering

Trying to render Japanese Kanji:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,svgnames,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont[BoldFont=STHeiti,ItalicFont=STKaiti]{STSong}
\begin{document}
Suzuki Matoshi (鈴木眞年).

\textbf{Suzuki Matoshi (鈴木眞年).}

\textit{Suzuki Matoshi (鈴木眞年).}
\end{document}
```

**Error(s):**

```
Critical Package xeCJK Error: The xeCJK package requires XeTeX to function.
```

I do not use `XeTeX`, I use `pdfLaTeX`. Is there smoothing equivalent for it?

Comment: Really, using pdfLaTeX for non-European scripts is a bad idea: what's the reason you can't change?

Comment: while it is possible to use pdftex for CJK you don't really want that nowadays. Use xelatex or lualatex (with luatex-ja).

Comment: pdftex fonts only have 256 characters so to cover CJK you need to have _lot_ of fonts, this subsetting was done for one or two fonts but was a massive amount of work and really you can only use the fonts provided. If you use xetex or luatex you can use any font on your system.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, what package can then be used?

Comment: as you show in your question. (oh do you mean package for pdftex)  possibly this https://ctan.org/pkg/cjk?lang=en

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, that does not work.

Comment: why can't you use xelatex?

Comment: ctex package says (I think) it works with pdftex to some extent, but I don't have the fonts and can not read the doc https://mirror.apps.cam.ac.uk/pub/tex-archive/language/chinese/ctex/ctex.pdf

Comment: @DavidCarlisle because it changes the font style all over my document. Every section that was bold because unbold etc. I am in Europe writing my thesis in English, and wanted some japanese characters to display.

Comment: if you use luatex you should be able to use pretty much the same font style (or even exactly the same fonts if you do not insist on unicode) perhaps you should instead ask a different question about why your font style is changing

Comment: but google shows some examples of using CJK names with pdflatex eg here https://journals.aas.org/nonroman/  (which is for aas class in the example but that is not needed)

Comment: `newunicodechar` could help. But note that a lot of zh fonts won't have all ja kanji in them. You will need ja fonts. (Note also that bold and italic are not really CJK concepts, although ja has mincho and gothic, and zh has "grass style".)

Comment: if you have only a few chars, the easiest is to create small pdf's with xelatex or lualatex and the standalone class and then include them with \includegraphics into your pdftex document.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I want to have the characters displayed inline with the English text, e.g., **Satoshi Nakamoto** (サトシ・ナカモト).

Comment: that is quite possible. Graphics can be small, and if you have one for every char you can even have a line break between them. You could even define `サ` so that it fetches the right graphic.

Comment: You will need a Japanese font or fonts, whichever method you use, just like you need a Greek font for writing Greek. `polyglossia` or `babel` for multi-script text. But it sounds like a suitable font sufficiently meets your needs.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31685/texing-special-japanese-characters